# static site apache and dynamic/member site django

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a site for static content, accessible to all that runs on apache.  As an adjunct to that, there is a members site that runs on django.  I haven't had any issue 'sharing' my .css and making both sides equivalent in appearance, but what I can't quite seem to grok is getting my django site to be django password protected (with the additional caveat that all member material, from the login forward, goes through 443).

I can serve all the pages, I have tried to use mod_rewrite as follows:

```
<Directory /Library/Webserver/Documents>
.
.
.
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /members /usr/local/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi 


<Directory /members>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
.
.
</Directory>
```

I have tried every one of a thousand different items in the '/members location above, nothing seems to hit (and yes, RewriteEngine On is included - I can watch the debug come out).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

You should be redirecting back to same host the request was made against, not necessarily the actual web server host.

I also don't believe there is a %{URI} variable in mod_rewrite. Supposed to use %{REQUEST_URI}.

---

EDIT 1

As per comments, should be:

```
<Location /members>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
.
.
</Location>
```

or:

```
<Directory /usr/local/django/mysite/apache>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
.
.
</Directory>
```

So, Location is for URL and Directory is for file system directory.

Comment: Sorry, part of what I did was from memory, didn't have the machine right in front of me.  It's not the rewritecond/rewriterule that has me stumped, it's getting them to fire.  I have placed them in every imaginable <Directory> config and they never seem to hit.  (Small clarification, if I do this with a regular directory, it works fine, it seems to be that I can't ascertain the correct DJANGO <Directory> structure to place the above lines into.)

Comment: That is because you should be using 'Location' and not 'Directory' if the argument is a URL. If want to use 'Directory' should be the location of the WSGI script file, but then you can't restrict it to a sub URL of whole site. So, use 'Location'. Go read the Apache documentation on the difference between 'Location' and 'Directory'.

Comment: Graham, thanks a million - give me a bit to read and then come back and mark your answer accepted.  Your reputation precedes you, so I'm pretty sure this will be a short search.

Comment: Bummer, no affect at all.  It seems my Location/Directory never get matched as I never see anything except "init rewrite engine with requested uri /members" and "pass through /members" in my rewrite.log

Comment: You sure then you haven't mucked up your VirtualHost definitions and is actually matching against wrong VirtualHost. Instead of the rewrite, add in a 'Deny from all' to even see if that section is being used. If it is, you should get forbidden error.

Comment: This isn't in extra/httpd-vhosts.conf, this is all in my main httpd.conf.  Should this be setup as two virtual hosts, one for my :80 and another for my :443?  If so, how would it ever be possible to NOT be in HTTP if all django was that VirtualHost?

Comment: Addenda, when I add Deny from all to my <Location> section, it does indeed deny me.  So, how is my RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off being missed?